# How can I split data in a cell to existing columns on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In MS Excel, I have cells that contain data separated with a semicolon. For example one cell could have the following data: Apple;Banana;Watermelon (see Starting state figure)

I also have columns labeled as "Apple", "Banana", etc. I need to somehow split this data so that the splitted part of the data goes to corresponding column (see Desired state figure).

[Starting state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2iS3.jpg)

[Desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7JVt.jpg)

I have tried using the data tool called "Data to columns" but I only managed to split the data of the cell but not place the result data parts to correct positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$1,$A2)),B$1,"")
```

and copy both across and downward:

[image]

*(The dollar signs in the formula are important)*

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @user13797882  You are quite welcome.